# Array.prototype.values() NOT WORKING like MDN example?

Tags: javascript, methods

[image]

```
var a = ['w', 'y', 'k', 'o', 'p']; 
var iterator = a.values();

console.log(iterator.next().value);
```

There are Tow example and the tow not working **why ?**

can You provide working example ?

This is the link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values

**Edite:**
This Code Working and no problem with using **value**

```
var arr = ['w', 'y', 'k', 'o', 'p'];
var eArr = arr[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(eArr.next().value);
```

I think It's Not Browser compatibility because i tested The first and last in same browser version

Thanks

Comment: please add the code in text form to the question.

Comment: Take a look at the browser compatibility. (e.g.: chrome 66+)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic cause you just need to update your browser, or change to one that supports the `values` method

Comment: I checked update and no chrome 66 available just this [Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

Comment: use a polyfill `if (typeof Array.prototype.values !== 'function') Array.prototype.values = function* () {for (cost x of this) yield x;};`

Comment: @Jonas W I think it's not browser update issue now look at the edited ... Finally Thanks for all of you